# Item removed from one collection is removed from second collection implicitly too, why?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

This is was big confusion for me. I have following code:

```
IEnumerable<WorkflowStateData> data = model.Data.Except(
            request.WorkflowState.CustomData.Select(x => new Model.WorkflowStateData {Key = x.Key}),
            new WorkflowStateDataEqualityComparer());
        foreach (var item in data) // makes the comparison (and exception) based on the value of property 'Key'
        {
            model.Data.Remove(item);
            stateDataSet.Remove(item);
        }
```

This should create new collection of items and use it for enumeration using foreach. It should remove items from original collection, but it removes it both from original collection and from "data" collection and throws InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified. Why?

Comment: it is reference to the same objects in memory that's why

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Except` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` of the set difference but it does it deferred which means it is still only the query. So everytime you would "touch" `data` you would execute this query. So if you want a "materialized" collection you have to use `ToList`, `ToArray`, `ToLookup` or `ToDictionary` (or add the result from a `foreach`-loop into another collection).

Normally you should even get an exception if you try to modify the collection that you are currently enumerating in a `foreach`. So you could use `ToList`  to create a real collection which is not afffected if you modify it's source:

```
List<WorkflowStateData> data = model.Data.Except(
        request.WorkflowState.CustomData.Select(x => new Model.WorkflowStateData {Key = x.Key}),
        new WorkflowStateDataEqualityComparer())
    .ToList();
```

Now you can remove the object(s) from the original collection without removing it from the list.

You should read about LINQ's deferred execution / eager evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is pretty simple, but not obvious because of use of that traitorous "var" keyword. [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) returns IEnumerable, not ICollection. IEnumerable could be imagined as view to specific collection, it is not collection on its own. So when item was removed from original collection, my enumerable was changed too.